# How to rename or create a zip file with the name of its content using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch and a vbs file to zip a folder with a specific directory name and copy it to another folder.

Does anyone have a clue how to zip a folder with the name of its content (filename) expanding the existing script I have?

With the following two scripts I can make the directories to be zipped and copied to another folder.

bat:

```
CScript zip.vbs C:\TEMP\zip\source\JEAR_20190115 C:\TEMP\zip\target\JEAR.zip
```

vbs:

```
'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, 
True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

Running the batch file which calls the vbs the folder's content (3 files) are zipped and copied to the target directory described in the bat file (C:\TEMP\zip\target\JEAR.zip).

The output filename is specified in the bat file but the goal is to have the filename of the zipped folder's content (filename). Which is JEAR_20180116.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, I think you want to just take the string, split off the last directory name and then use that as a variable in setting your zip file:

```
@echo off
set "mypath=C:\TEMP\zip\source\JEAR_20190115"
if "%mypath:~-1%"=="\" set "mypath=%mypath:~0,-1%"
for %%i in (%mypath%) do set "last=%%~nxi"
CScript zip.vbs %mypath% C:\TEMP\zip\target\%last%.zip
```

Please take note, if you change your path to have a trailing backslash on your path i.e:

```
C:\TEMP\zip\source\JEAR_20190115\
```

You would want to first get rid of that, but we could simply test for it with:

```
if "%mypath:~-1%"=="\" set "mypath=%mypath:~0,-1%"
```

So then the full script will be:

```
@echo off
set "mypath=C:\TEMP\zip\source\JEAR_20190115"
if "%mypath:~-1%"=="\" set "mypath=%mypath:~0,-1%"
for %%i in (%mypath%) do set "last=%%~nxi"
CScript zip.vbs %mypath% C:\TEMP\zip\target\%last%.zip
```

if however the if you want to name it to a file within the directory, you would need to be sure the filenames inside the folder are all the same, as we will only be able to set it using one name, which will be the last file in the list, we could check each name, but I assume you haev files with the same name, but different extensions:

```
@echo off
set "mypath=C:\TEMP\zip\source\JEAR_20190115"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "%mypath%"') do set "last=%%~ni"
CScript zip.vbs %mypath% C:\TEMP\zip\target\%last%.zip
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. After testing I can say it is working properly. Is it possible to do the same method with the source file name pattern ? For example don't search for JEAR_20190115 folder but JEAR_YYYYMMDD or only if the folder contains the current date(today) or the folder's creation date is today?

Comment: @Ilya_Kuvshi, it is possible yes, but please ask a new quesiton, then just link this question to it and I will answer it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54235365/7420833